# Should structs be typedef'd in a C library?

Tags: c, struct, alias

First off, I am well aware of the concepts behind using `typedef` on both names and anonymous `struct`s. My question is how a C library should expose its types.

Typically, I would simply `typedef` an anonymous `struct`, or a named `struct` when I need forward declaration. However, this is an issue if a library with only `typedef`s is included in a project that prefers using the `struct` qualifier, which is no longer possible. Similarly, having both a `typedef` and a named `struct` may still pollute the general namespace for such projects.

Should a library, then, only provide named structures and leave `typedef`ing to the user?

Comment: Both `struct name` and `name` are available to the translation unit including something with `typedef struct name name;`. So I don't understand your question..

Comment: The standard C library uses `typedef`in `<stdint.h>` for various integer types and structured types like `div_t` and friends.   Yet is uses `struct tm` and `struct lconv`.  As the standard library goes both ways,  it does not follow a _should_ or _should not_ answer to your question.  IOWs, use your group's coding standards - it is a style issue.